# Vue Call Method when div Size Changes

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

How do I execute some method each time the size (width or height) of a `div` changes?

```
<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        redraw() {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You could of used `new ResizeObserver(() => {}).observe(this.$refs.some_div)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver - if your div was actually resizable

Comment: see: https://playcode.io/842526/

Answer (score 0):

You could define width and height on data dynamically and then make a watch on these sizes. Something like this:

**UPDATE** The comment of Lawrence Cherone made me realize an error I made here.

```
<template>
  <div :style="{width: divWidth, height: divHeight}">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data():{
        return {
           divWidth: '100px',
           divHeight: '100px'
        }
    },
    watch: {
        divWidth (newVal){
           if(newVal){
               this.redraw()
           }
        },
        divHeight (newVal){
           if(newVal){
               this.redraw()
           }
        },
    methods: {
        redraw() {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: your solution won't work, did you try it?

Comment: No. I just gave you an idea of how you can resolve your problem. I can't do much with the sample you put here.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you weren't the person who asked . Can you point the error here for me, please?